# How to automatically scroll down to new data after user form input

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to come up with a way for my spreadsheet to scroll down to the newest data that was added from a user form. 
`.Range("A1" & ActiveCell.Row).Select` does not seem to work, as all it does is select the data but not go to the data

Comment: Look at `Application.Goto`

Comment: If you're working with the active window, [`Range.Show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.show) also works.

Comment: Look at the Application.Goto method's optional *Scroll* argument.

Comment: @Tim Williams thanks! Works perfectly.